# Slim Application Error (website error occurred)

Tags: php, api, slim

Good day ! I always get this error " (A website error has occurred. Sorry for the temporary inconvenience)." every time I try to run my codes in postman. And here's my codes.

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../includes/DBOperations.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;


$app->post('/createClient', function(Request $request, Response $response){

if(!haveEmptyParameters(array('lastname','firstname','midname','contactnum','emailadd','password'),$response)){

$request_data = $request->getParseBody();
$lastname = $request_data['lastname'];
$firstname = $request_data['firstname'];
$midname = $request_data['midname'];
$contactnum = $request_data['contactnum'];
$emailadd = $request_data['emailadd'];
$password = $request_data['password'];
$hash_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$db = new DBOperations;
```

Comment: I'd first suggest adding a config array to the slim app instantiation, which allows for the displaying of errors, `$config = ['settings' => ['displayErrorDetails' => true]]; $app = new Slim\App($config);` just remember to remove the config when making the code live! (or at least turn the errors off https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/application.html#application-configuration

Comment: where should i add that configuration ?

Comment: Just before you do you `$app = new Slim\App`, I've linked some documentation in my first comment :)

Answer (score 4):

The comment from @Dale about adding the below LOC helps:

```
$config = ['settings' => ['displayErrorDetails' => true]]; 
$app = new Slim\App($config);
```